# Twitter Bootstrap 3.1 Nav-stacked Spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm quite new at coding for HTML and all that sort of business so I decided I was going to use an already built and sturdy API. Therefore, I chose Twitter Bootstrap 3.1 as I've had *some* prior experience with it.

Anyway, this is what my current nav-stacked looks like. It's CSS is fairly butchered as I wanted it to be collapsible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnRZ0.jpg

And here is the code for that particular section of code. I got rid of the repeating parts to save space.

```
<div class="col-xs-3 sidebar" id="ASEsideNav">
          <!This is left Vertical Nav bar>
          <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="ASEsideNav">              
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ASEsideNav">
              <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu-bar"> <!-- Notice the "nav-stacked" class we added here -->
                <!-- We add the panel class to workaround collapsing menu items in Bootstrap -->
                <li class="panel dropdown">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-bar" href="#collapse1"> Safety</a>
                  <!-- Notice the ID of this element must match the href attribute in the <a> element above it. Also we have added the panel-collapse class -->
                  <ul id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <li><a href="#">Guardwell Perimeter Safety Products</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="panel dropdown">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-bar" href="#collapse2"> Kettles</a>
                  <ul id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <li><a href="#">Patch Kettles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Asphalt Kettles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kettle Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Heat Transfer Kettles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Emission Control System</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

            </div>
          </div> <!End of navbar>
        </div>
```

As you can see, it's been pretty butchered. This is my rendition of someone else's code from a different page. That page being as so:
http://www.jeffmould.com/2013/12/15/create-twitter-bootstrap-vertical-drop-menu/

The CSS he used compared to mine is quite different as I don't have the nav-bar hanging from the top left. **Anyway**, my question is, there are large spacings between each individual button and I can't figure out which or what ID or Class is dictating that spacing. I would like them to be brought much closer together if possible.

I apologize if my wording or phrasing is poor, I've only just started coding HTML so I'm quite behind on most of the possible standards?

TL;DR - The root buttons in my nav-stacked collapse drop menu are way too far apart, as you can see from the picture linked above, how do I bring them closer together? I would assume CSS but I don't know what Class is interacting with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've applied the class `.panel` to the `<li>` elements in your menu (I'm not sure why). Bootstrap applies 20px of bottom margin to elements with that class.

From the bootstrap CSS:

```
.panel {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

You can fix it with this:

```
#ASEsideNav .panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You might want to check out Firefox' Firebug. It has a CSS panel that will help you to sort through this sort of stuff. https://getfirebug.com/css. Chrome and IE have similar tools built in.

Comment: Oh my God! Thank you so much, haha. Such an easy fix. I've been staring at this and mucking about it for the last hour. I really appreciate it dude! I've been using Firefox's default tools; such as "inspect element" and "view page source" for almost the entire website creation. I can only assume GetFireBug has much more functionality than what's available to me with just Firefox so I'll definitely look into it right now. But yes, I applied that as that's what the gentleman in the post I linked did. It works I suppose?